# Is it possible to get premium characters and worlds without paying?

Tags: final-fantasy-all-the-bravest

I finished the game and wanted to see the premium characters and worlds. Is there a way to do this without shelling out almost $47?

Comment: Based on various reviews of the game stating that it's basically microtransactions hell, I'm guessing for the time being, no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. Unless you wanted to work around the game's code, premium characters and worlds will cost you a pretty penny. Even if you were going to manipulate the code, I'm not sure if the data for the premium content is even there to be accessed.